# Bootstrap 3 "row" class not working on mobile?

Tags: css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

The front page of my website [wisderm.com](http://wisderm.com) has the Twitter Follow and Facebook buttons next to each other. On mobile though, the Facebook buttons are not on the same line as the Twitter button, even though I've put them in a div with the class "row".

```
<!-- Social -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/wisderm" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-lang="en">Follow @wisderm</a>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/wisdermcom" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
</div><!-- end of row -->
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

Why is this? Is it because the Twitter button is in an iframe? And how can I fix it?

Image on my Nexus 4: [Messed up Facebook and Twitter buttons](http://tinypic.com/r/6ru7wn/8)

Image for when using `display: inline !important`: [Messed up buttons 2](http://tinypic.com/r/2i92tko/8)

Comment: can you share an image how it is displayed at your end?

Comment: sure Nimmi, I've added a photo of how it looks like on my Nexus 4.

Comment: Please try by adding display: inline; to your fb-like class. 
`.fb-like { display:inline; }`

Comment: Ok, I've added it. It doesn't seem to be working though, darn.

Comment: One last suggestion I can help is please add !important with display might work :(

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work :( Thanks for trying to help though! EDIT: Oh actually it seems to work partially! It makes the fb buttons a lot lower though.

Comment: One thing I can suggest try to put it in ul li it should work 
Inspect this [link](http://www.bootply.com/) in firebug and see the logo.

Comment: screenshot please as I dont have nexus or not much aware for simulator for nexus :)

Comment: sorry, I was trying out your other suggestion of using a list and forgot about the screenshot. I've added it now!

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc86Q/2/)

Comment: That worked!!! This was what I did: added a ``social-buttons`` class to the ``ul`` element and made ``.social-buttons li`` ``float: left`` and ``list-style: none`` in my css like in your fiddle. Thank you so much, if you could post your answer below I'd gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ul and li and apply CSS like below on li(you can also use class).

```
ul li {
float:left;
list-style:none;
margin-right:1em;
}
```